# How do I connect Kafkajs with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, socket.io, kafkajs

I've been studying kafkajs and socket.io I'm am very new to it and i cant seem to understand some things.
I have created a chat application that basically by opening a browser(client) you can type messages and they get displayed in a chat-window.
I found a tutorial that makes kafka print "this message + i".
I want to instead of sending to the topic and printing message+i to print what people type in chat and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do that.

**This is my consumer.js:**

```
const { Kafka } = require("kafkajs")
const clientId = "my-app"
const brokers = ["localhost:9092"]
const topic = "message-log"

const kafka = new Kafka({ clientId, brokers })
// create a new consumer from the kafka client, and set its group ID
// the group ID helps Kafka keep track of the messages that this client
// is yet to receive
const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: clientId })

const consume = async () => {
    // first, we wait for the client to connect and subscribe to the given topic
    await consumer.connect()
    await consumer.subscribe({ topic })
    await consumer.run({
        // this function is called every time the consumer gets a new message
        eachMessage: ({ message }) => {
            // here, we just log the message to the standard output
            console.log(`received message: ${message.value}`)
        },
    })
}

module.exports = consume
```

**This is my producer.js:**

```
// import the `Kafka` instance from the kafkajs library
const { Kafka } = require("kafkajs")

// the client ID lets kafka know who's producing the messages
const clientId = "my-app"
// we can define the list of brokers in the cluster
const brokers = ["localhost:9092"]
// this is the topic to which we want to write messages
const topic = "message-log"

// initialize a new kafka client and initialize a producer from it
const kafka = new Kafka({ clientId, brokers })
const producer = kafka.producer()

// we define an async function that writes a new message each second
const produce = async () => {
    await producer.connect()
    let i = 0

    // after the produce has connected, we start an interval timer
    setInterval(async () => {
        try {
            // send a message to the configured topic with
            // the key and value formed from the current value of `i`
            await producer.send({
                topic,
                messages: [
                    {
                        key: String(i),
                        value: "this is message " + i,
                    },
                ],
            })

            // if the message is written successfully, log it and increment `i`
            console.log("writes: ", i)
            i++
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("could not write message " + err)
        }
    }, 1000)
}

module.exports = produce
```

I know I'm supposed to somehow connect the topics brokers and clients with the socket.io but I'm not sure how.

**Here is my chat.js:**

```
/* Kane connection sto server opos prin
exw tin ikanotita na xrhsimopoihsw to io logo tou library pou phra apo to documentation*/
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

// linking Variables toy indexhtml
var message = document.getElementById('message');
var username = document.getElementById('username');
var btn = document.getElementById('send');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

// Stelnw events pou ginonte apo ton xristi kai stelnonte ston server
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('chat', {
        message: message.value,
        username: username.value
    });
    message.value = "";
});

message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    socket.emit('typing', username.value);
})

// Events wste na perimenw to data apo ton server
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '';
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.username + ': </strong>' + data.message + '</p>';
});

socket.on('typing', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em>' + data + ' is typing a message...</em></p>';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a socket.io server.

Example:

```
const consume = require('consumer.js');
const produce = require('producer.js');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server();

consume(({ from, to, message }) => {
  io.sockets.emit('newMessage', { from, to, message });
})

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('Hi!', { message: 'Chat connected', id: socket.id });
  
  socket.on('sendMessage', ({ message, to }) => {
     produce({ from: socket.id, to, message });
  });
  
});
```

You also need to modify your consumer & producer to accept parameters and callbacks.

Consumer Example:

```
...
const consume = async cb => {
    // first, we wait for the client to connect and subscribe to the given topic
    await consumer.connect()
    await consumer.subscribe({ topic })
    await consumer.run({
        // this function is called every time the consumer gets a new message
        eachMessage: ({ from, to, message }) => {
            cb({ from, to, message });
        },
    });
}
```

Producer Example:

```
const produce = async ({ from, to, message }) => {
    producer.send(topic, { from, to, message });
}
```

Don't forget to modify your chat.js on the client side

All of this can be optimized and is just a brief example

Comment: Thank you so much.I've been studying the documentation but they are not very newbie friendly.I'm in an internship and its so hard for me to understand some things especially the reason why they would want to directly consume and produce from the browser.